# Chart.js ungroup data in tooltip with multiple lines

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, chart.js

I'm looking for an answer similar to a previous question:

Link: [chart js tooltip how to control the data that show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24868577/chart-js-tooltip-how-to-control-the-data-that-show)

But I need a solution for a Line Chart via Chart.js. I'm wanting a line chart with multiple lines and I would like each point to return only the data for that point in the tooltip. By default the tooltip returns data in a group for each point at the index you hover over. So I would want each point to only return it's data and have it's own tooltip box.

See default example of line chart : http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#line-chart

It would also be nice if I could have all the tooltips displayed by default and not triggered by a mouse hover.